# Retrieve user infos through AdMob ID

Tags: android, admob, ads

Can someone get my personal informations with my app id? 
I mean, if ill put my publisher id inside an app, and someone finds it, can someone know its me? 
Im also talking about public authorities, literally anyone, if you ask to an admob employee, they can make that 'public'?

Comment: To know more about app id https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356431?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Public authorities can get any information they need from Google (which owns Android, AdMob, AdSense, and YouTube) as long as they get the permission of a judge. The average person cannot get someone's personal information using a Publisher Id. Google must protect their users's private information according to their privacy policy which they present to you when you sign up for an AdMob account. Only Google, and the companies they own, have access to your Publisher Id and any information associated with it. They only use it to provide you with the services you use.